# QGIS 3 Processing tools don't seem to work (can't load output)

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, saga, network

I've got a new machine running on Win10 (I was previously on Win7) and I can no longer use... pretty much any algorithm, especially from SAGA.

It's probably something to do with environment variables, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to find out what. I've been searching around all day long without success.

So, I'm basically trying to split lines on points. I've been doing that with either Networks plugin (Connect nodes to lines) or SAGA (Split lines at points).
It seems that the tools can't generate the output. I get a .prj file, but none of the other components of a Shapefile.

I tried fixing geomtries. I made sure projections were not an issue. As this same workflow worked last week, I tried with previous versions of QGIS. No success.

From what I can see, deprecated parts seem to be implied. What I do not get is that these tools worked last week without any change in software update in between...

I'm using QGIS 3.10

Here are the logs. First for SAGA, then for Networks plugin:

EDIT: the Networks plugin indeed simply was using deprecated tools. Updating them solved the problem. Still having problems with SAGA.

---

SAGA

```
QGIS version: 3.10.0-A Coruña
QGIS code revision: 6ffa89eb3e
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.0.2
GEOS version: 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 
PROJ version: Rel. 6.2.1, November 1st, 2019
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Split lines at points' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'EPSILON' : 0, 'INTERSECT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'LINES' : 'MultiLineString?crs=EPSG:2950&field=feature_id:string(32,0)&field=datemin:string(8,0)&field=datemax:string(8,0)&field=haccmin:double(18,10)&field=haccmax:double(18,10)&field=perm:long(16,0)&field=perm_en:string(12,0)&field=perm_fr:string(12,0)&field=qualif:long(16,0)&field=qualif_en:string(8,0)&field=qualif_fr:string(48,0)&field=priority:long(16,0)&field=priorityen:string(7,0)&field=priorityfr:string(8,0)&field=definit:long(16,0)&field=definit_en:string(11,0)&field=definit_fr:string(11,0)&field=fldir:long(16,0)&field=fldir_en:string(14,0)&field=fldir_fr:string(55,0)&field=name_db:string(1,0)&field=name_id:string(1,0)&field=name_en:string(1,0)&field=name_fr:string(1,0)&field=nameoth:string(1,0)&field=langoth:string(1,0)&field=name_1_id:string(1,0)&field=name_1_en:string(1,0)&field=name_1_fr:string(1,0)&field=name_2_id:string(1,0)&field=name_2_en:string(1,0)&field=name_2_fr:string(1,0)&field=map_sel:long(16,0)&field=map_sel_en:string(5,0)&field=map_sel_fr:string(5,0)&field=ctry:long(16,0)&field=ctry_en:string(6,0)&field=ctry_fr:string(6,0)&field=topolqu:long(16,0)&field=topolqu_en:string(14,0)&field=topolqu_fr:string(54,0)&field=netqual:long(16,0)&field=netqual_en:string(14,0)&field=netqual_fr:string(54,0)&field=OBJECTID:long(16,0)&field=NO_SEQ_COU:double(18,10)&field=NO_COURS_D:string(1,0)&field=NOM_COURS_:string(1,0)&field=NIVEAU_BAS:long(16,0)&field=NO_REG_HYD:string(2,0)&field=ECHELLE:string(7,0)&field=DAT_MAJ:string(10,0)&field=ENTITE:string(22,0)&field=SUP_KM2:double(18,10)&field=SHAPE_Leng:double(18,10)&field=SHAPE_Area:double(18,10)&field=feature_le:double(18,10)&field=id:long(16,0)&field=length_km:double(18,10)&field=feature__1:string(1,0)&field=datemin_2:string(1,0)&field=datemax_2:string(1,0)&field=haccmin_2:double(18,10)&field=haccmax_2:double(18,10)&field=perm_2:long(16,0)&field=perm_en_2:string(1,0)&field=perm_fr_2:string(1,0)&field=qualif_2:long(16,0)&field=qualif_en_:string(1,0)&field=qualif_fr_:string(1,0)&field=priority_2:long(16,0)&field=priority_1:string(1,0)&field=priority_3:string(1,0)&field=definit_2:long(16,0)&field=definit__1:string(1,0)&field=definit__2:string(1,0)&field=fldir_2:long(16,0)&field=fldir_en_2:string(1,0)&field=fldir_fr_2:string(1,0)&field=name_db_2:string(1,0)&field=name_id_2:string(1,0)&field=name_en_2:string(1,0)&field=name_fr_2:string(1,0)&field=nameoth_2:string(1,0)&field=langoth_2:string(1,0)&field=name_1_id_:string(1,0)&field=name_1_en_:string(1,0)&field=name_1_fr_:string(1,0)&field=name_2_id_:string(1,0)&field=name_2_en_:string(1,0)&field=name_2_fr_:string(1,0)&field=map_sel_2:long(16,0)&field=map_sel__1:string(1,0)&field=map_sel__2:string(1,0)&field=ctry_2:long(16,0)&field=ctry_en_2:string(1,0)&field=ctry_fr_2:string(1,0)&field=topolqu_2:long(16,0)&field=topolqu__1:string(1,0)&field=topolqu__2:string(1,0)&field=netqual_2:long(16,0)&field=netqual__1:string(1,0)&field=netqual__2:string(1,0)&field=OBJECTID_2:long(16,0)&field=NO_SEQ_C_1:double(18,10)&field=NO_COURS_1:string(1,0)&field=NOM_COUR_1:string(1,0)&field=NIVEAU_B_1:long(16,0)&field=NO_REG_H_1:string(1,0)&field=ECHELLE_2:string(1,0)&field=DAT_MAJ_2:string(1,0)&field=ENTITE_2:string(1,0)&field=SUP_KM2_2:double(18,10)&field=SHAPE_Le_1:double(18,10)&field=SHAPE_Ar_1:double(18,10)&field=feature__2:double(18,10)&field=id_2:long(16,0)&field=length_km_:double(18,10)&field=feature__3:string(1,0)&field=datemin_3:string(1,0)&field=datemax_3:string(1,0)&field=haccmin_3:double(18,10)&field=haccmax_3:double(18,10)&field=perm_3:long(16,0)&field=perm_en_3:string(1,0)&field=perm_fr_3:string(1,0)&field=qualif_3:long(16,0)&field=qualif_e_1:string(1,0)&field=qualif_f_1:string(1,0)&field=priority_4:long(16,0)&field=priority_5:string(1,0)&field=priority_6:string(1,0)&field=definit_3:long(16,0)&field=definit__3:string(1,0)&field=definit__4:string(1,0)&field=fldir_3:long(16,0)&field=fldir_en_3:string(1,0)&field=fldir_fr_3:string(1,0)&field=name_db_3:string(1,0)&field=name_id_3:string(1,0)&field=name_en_3:string(1,0)&field=name_fr_3:string(1,0)&field=nameoth_3:string(1,0)&field=langoth_3:string(1,0)&field=name_1_i_1:string(1,0)&field=name_1_e_1:string(1,0)&field=name_1_f_1:string(1,0)&field=name_2_i_1:string(1,0)&field=name_2_e_1:string(1,0)&field=name_2_f_1:string(1,0)&field=map_sel_3:long(16,0)&field=map_sel__3:string(1,0)&field=map_sel__4:string(1,0)&field=ctry_3:long(16,0)&field=ctry_en_3:string(1,0)&field=ctry_fr_3:string(1,0)&field=topolqu_3:long(16,0)&field=topolqu__3:string(1,0)&field=topolqu__4:string(1,0)&field=netqual_3:long(16,0)&field=netqual__3:string(1,0)&field=netqual__4:string(1,0)&field=OBJECTID_3:long(16,0)&field=NO_SEQ_C_2:double(18,10)&field=NO_COURS_2:string(1,0)&field=NOM_COUR_2:string(1,0)&field=NIVEAU_B_2:long(16,0)&field=NO_REG_H_2:string(1,0)&field=ECHELLE_3:string(1,0)&field=DAT_MAJ_3:string(1,0)&field=ENTITE_3:string(1,0)&field=SUP_KM2_3:double(18,10)&field=SHAPE_Le_2:double(18,10)&field=SHAPE_Ar_2:double(18,10)&field=feature__4:double(18,10)&field=id_3:long(16,0)&field=length_k_1:double(18,10)&field=Bord:string(1,0)&uid={a34070c7-bb21-4671-8963-907fc418e745}', 'OUTPUT' : 1, 'SPLIT' : 'MultiPoint?crs=EPSG:2950&field=OBJECTID:long(16,0)&field=EEE_Type:string(3,0)&field=Date:date(10,0)&field=Type:string(3,0)&field=Comment:string(254,0)&field=Ero_Long:long(16,0)&field=Ero_Type:long(16,0)&field=Ero_Force:long(16,0)&field=Ero_Trav:long(16,0)&field=Ero_Prio:long(16,0)&field=Station:string(5,0)&field=EEE_Longue:long(16,0)&field=Obt_Type1:string(3,0)&field=Obt_Type2:string(3,0)&field=Obt_Type3:string(1,0)&field=Obt_Prio:long(16,0)&field=Obt_Stat:string(3,0)&field=NbType:long(16,0)&field=RecLimon:long(16,0)&field=Subs_Enlis:long(16,0)&field=MinBerg:long(16,0)&field=VegSurp:long(16,0)&field=Recif:long(16,0)&field=FossProf:long(16,0)&field=DebrLign:long(16,0)&field=Racin:long(16,0)&field=Couv_Bloc:long(16,0)&field=Meand:long(16,0)&field=Macrop:long(16,0)&field=Qt_Couv:long(16,0)&field=Sinuo:long(16,0)&field=CompRapFo:long(16,0)&field=Canal:long(16,0)&field=Stabil:long(16,0)&field=DLarg:string(1,0)&field=DUtilTer:string(1,0)&field=DEros:string(1,0)&field=GLarg:string(1,0)&field=GUtilTer:string(1,0)&field=GEros:string(1,0)&field=Morpho:long(16,0)&field=ERZmax:long(16,0)&field=Subst:long(16,0)&field=Enlis:long(16,0)&field=DLargRepl:double(18,10)&field=DLHE:double(18,10)&field=DAngPente:long(16,0)&field=DArbr:long(16,0)&field=DArbu:long(16,0)&field=DHerba:long(16,0)&field=DCoupFor:long(16,0)&field=DPrairFi:long(16,0)&field=DPatu:long(16,0)&field=DCult:long(16,0)&field=DSolNu:long(16,0)&field=DSocRoc:long(16,0)&field=DInfra:long(16,0)&field=DGazon:long(16,0)&field=GLargRepl:double(18,10)&field=GLHE:double(18,10)&field=GAngPente:long(16,0)&field=GArbr:long(16,0)&field=GArbu:long(16,0)&field=GHerba:long(16,0)&field=GCoupFor:long(16,0)&field=GPrairFi:long(16,0)&field=GPatu:long(16,0)&field=GCult:long(16,0)&field=GSolNu:long(16,0)&field=GSocRoc:long(16,0)&field=GInfra:long(16,0)&field=GGazon:long(16,0)&field=ELZmax:long(16,0)&field=Courant:string(3,0)&field=EEE_Rive:string(1,0)&field=Subs_Type1:long(16,0)&field=Subs_Type2:long(16,0)&field=Ero_Rive:string(1,0)&field=Cult_Rive:string(1,0)&field=Cult_Obs:string(3,0)&field=Cult_Cult:string(2,0)&field=GlobalID:string(38,0)&field=CreationDa:date(10,0)&field=Creator:string(10,0)&field=EditDate:date(10,0)&field=Editor:string(10,0)&field=IQHP_Subst:string(2,0)&field=IQHP_Couv:string(2,0)&field=IQHP_Morph:string(2,0)&field=IQHP_ZoneE:string(5,0)&field=IQHP_EauxL:string(1,0)&field=IQHP_EauxR:string(1,0)&field=IQHP_Total:string(5,0)&field=IQBR_Droit:string(18,0)&field=IQBR_LargB:string(4,0)&field=IQBR_Angle:string(5,0)&field=IQBR_Gauch:string(18,0)&field=IQBR_Lar_1:string(4,0)&field=IQBR_Ang_1:string(5,0)&field=Eros_Type:string(2,0)&field=Eros_TypDe:string(48,0)&field=Eros_Force:string(1,0)&field=Eros_ForDe:string(6,0)&field=Eros_Prior:string(1,0)&field=Eros_PrioD:string(18,0)&uid={29ae3cca-66ee-4ae3-ab19-e5601b3aa856}' }

shapes_lines "Split Lines at Points" -LINES "C:/Users/miche/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ddda4adf9cc741d6a61e4800cfd6e577/fbf74854a1ff4c6e93a77cc892df947a/LINES.shp" -SPLIT "C:/Users/miche/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ddda4adf9cc741d6a61e4800cfd6e577/caa8f9e6977b45069d083a267216afd1/SPLIT.shp" -OUTPUT 1 -EPSILON 0.0 -INTERSECT "C:/Users/miche/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ddda4adf9cc741d6a61e4800cfd6e577/0c581958a97a401e8cfb51b73ec6a961/INTERSECT.shp"

C:\Users\miche\Documents>set SAGA=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps\saga-ltr

C:\Users\miche\Documents>set SAGA_MLB=C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\Users\miche\Documents>PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\qgis\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\grass\grass78\lib;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\grass\grass78\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\qt5\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps\saga-ltr;C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\Users\miche\Documents>call saga_cmd shapes_lines "Split Lines at Points" -LINES "C:/Users/miche/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ddda4adf9cc741d6a61e4800cfd6e577/fbf74854a1ff4c6e93a77cc892df947a/LINES.shp" -SPLIT "C:/Users/miche/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ddda4adf9cc741d6a61e4800cfd6e577/caa8f9e6977b45069d083a267216afd1/SPLIT.shp" -OUTPUT 1 -EPSILON 0.0 -INTERSECT "C:/Users/miche/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ddda4adf9cc741d6a61e4800cfd6e577/0c581958a97a401e8cfb51b73ec6a961/INTERSECT.shp"
Error: Split Features
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: shapes_lines
library : Lines
tool : Split Lines at Points
author : O. Conrad (c) 2015
processors : 12 [12]
____________________________

Load shapes: C:/Users/miche/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ddda4adf9cc741d6a61e4800cfd6e577/fbf74854a1ff4c6e93a77cc892df947a/LINES.shp...


Load shapes: C:/Users/miche/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ddda4adf9cc741d6a61e4800cfd6e577/caa8f9e6977b45069d083a267216afd1/SPLIT.shp...



Usage: saga_cmd shapes_lines 8 [-LINES <str>] [-SPLIT <str>] [-INTERSECT <str>] [-OUTPUT <str>] [-EPSILON <double>]
-LINES:<str> Lines
Shapes (input)
-SPLIT:<str> Split Features
Shapes (input)
-INTERSECT:<str> Intersection
Shapes (output)
-OUTPUT:<str> Output
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] polylines
[1] separate lines
Default: 1
-EPSILON:<double> Epsilon
Floating point
Default: 0.000000

C:\Users\miche\Documents>exit
Execution completed in 4.57 seconds
Results:
{'INTERSECT': 'C:/Users/miche/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ddda4adf9cc741d6a61e4800cfd6e577/0c581958a97a401e8cfb51b73ec6a961/INTERSECT.shp'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/miche/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_ddda4adf9cc741d6a61e4800cfd6e577/0c581958a97a401e8cfb51b73ec6a961/INTERSECT.shp</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```